# Remove commas inside text but ignore the comma delimiters?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a google sheet where the contents of a particular cell is a comma separated list of names. The names are enclosed in double quotes but the names have commas in them as they are formatted as LastName Comma Space FirstName Space MiddleInitialIfGiven.
Looks like:

"Gilbert, Matthew C", "Wisters, Helena A", "Wisters, Michael", "Clark, Jim A", "Gilbert, Matthew C", etc (yes, there are duplicates in the cell). What formula(s) would I use to strip the commas WITHIN the text strings, but leave the comma delimiters? regexreplace() strips out *all* the commas in the cell.

The cell purposely has a list instead of a single value as it was pulled from another dataset. My end goal is getting the duplicates out of this list but for now I just want the commas inside the text strings gone. Unless it's dumb to approach it that way; if I don't have to take the commas out to get a list of unique names I'd rather do that and skip the extra step (but i am extremely curious as to how I *would* get the commas out. Google searches have come up empty for me on this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```cpp
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,",( \w)","$1")
```

[image]

**Explanation**

`,( \w)` - captures all the occurrences of <kbd>Space</kbd> followed by a word character `\w` if preceded by a comma `,`

`$1` - replaces everything `, \w` with the captured group  `\w`.

Comment: could you explain what the \w and $1 mean? I'm a n00b with all logic and especially with regular expressions.

Comment: `\w` is a shorthand for `[A-Za-z0-9_]` which indicates a word character. `$1` refers to the group 1 in the `regular_expression` field, which is everything enclosed within round brackets `( \w)`

Answer (score 1):

*Incase you just want the `unique` list of names:*

```js
=let(Σ,split(A3,""""),
     unique(filter(Σ,Σ<>", "),1))
```

`logic`:

1. splitting the name list by quotes `split(A3,"""")` & calling it `Σ` by using let function
2. filtering only the names by removing the remnant delimiter commas *from the list obtained in step 1* `filter(Σ,Σ<>", ")`
3. using `unique` function to remove duplicates

[image]

Comment: I'd be very interested in a breakdown of what all of this means as I have zero idea what i'm doing with formulas and logic....

Comment: logic/explanation of the formula added to the answer

Comment: Beautiful.  Had to give credit to the other poster for answering the question I posted but you got at what I was ultimately trying to get at, so throwing as many points your way as possible. Cheers!

Comment: Actually, when I do the same formula it does a mostly good job at filtering out all the duplicates....just populates the 2nd column with a lone comma. Like the comma is treated as an entry somehow.....

Comment: the input could be slightly different from what was tested above!

Comment: It's weird. I copied and pasted what you had changing only the cell name from A3 to H6 and it throws out that comma. I went to the dataset and removed all but the first two names and it spits out that comma. It's weird.

Comment: I figured it out! Inside filter(), the comma is noted as ", " with a space. If I remove the space and write it as "," the issue resolves. My dataset has no space after the comma